# How can I make a gallery of tumbnails of trending videos on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, gallery

I've been looking around and I'm just not sure where to start. I wanna make a gallery that displays the thumbnails of trending videos on my site, and when a thumbnail is clicked on it'll redirect the user to a page where the video is at. If anybody could let me know how to do this, point me in the direction of where to find out how to do this or even give some advice that'd be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at ffmpeg and then tell us what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a broad question so a high level answer:

- firstly, every time a video is viewed, record this info someplace in your system (I am guessing you already do this, hopefully)
- looking at your tags, I am assuming you are using JQuery so the following are examples of JQuery based video gallery: https://html5box.com/html5gallery/, https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery
- populate the video gallery above with the most watched videos from your records

Using these approaches you will need to generate a thumbnail 'poster' image for the videos. There are ways to do this automatically (e.g. see step 7 here using ffmpeg and node.js: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js--net-25445).

However, if you want to control the image used, which can make quite a difference to the appearance you will want to create the poster image yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah sorry for such a broad question, lol it was too broad to find an answer from googling it, but thanks for pointing me to the right steps. The advice is appreciated!